# Wordpress site down after installing a plugin. Can't connect with FTP with correct details

Tags: plugins

My site (weaselbandit.com) is down.
It went down after installing the Printify plugin.

I've tried installing the Filezilla and the WinSCP software to log in and disable the plugin that way, but neither of them will connect to the site.

I've tried searching everywhere for a solution but I can't find anything.
Please help me.

PS. I only have intermediate knowledge about this stuff so I might need it explained, like I'm an idiot.

Comment: Contact your host so you can get the correct FTP details. There must be something incorrect about them. A plugin should not be able to affect your ability to connect via FTP.

Comment: Alright, I called them and they say that they are updating their systems and that's why it went down. 
So I'm gonna have to wait up to 24 hours to see if it comes back online.
(Thanks for your answer @JacobPeattie )

Answer (score -1):

For sure you must solve the FTP connection since it's not related with the plugin error.
A possible solution if you have access to phpmyadmin:
open a sql window and type:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'active_plugins'
```

then delete the record. Note that `wp_options` may change if the prefix of your tables are different, you see them all beginnnig with a prefix + underscore (wp_, or wp123_ ,or XX_,...)

[image]

this will reset all active plugins and give you access to the site again